# C Shared Memory Reader-Writer Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, ubuntu

Here is a Synchronized Reader and Writer. The target is passing data between these two Processes via a Shared Memory.
The Writer opens a Shared Memory through a Structure and writes Some Data. I am getting Segmentation Fault(Core Dumped) error message.
The code is compiled through the following command in Ubuntu.

```
g++ Writer.c -o Writer -lrt
g++ Reader.c -o Reader -lrt
```

And these two Processes are run by-

```
./Writer
./Reader
```

The Writer.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main(void){
    struct MemData{
        char* FileName;
        int LastByteLength;
        int ReadPointer;
        int WritePointer;
        char Data[512000];//MEMORY BLOCK SIZE: 500 KB
    };
    int SD;
    struct MemData *M;
    int NumberOfBuffers=10;
    int BufferSize=51200;//FILE BUFFER SIZE 50 KB

    SD= shm_open("/program.shared", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, S_IREAD|S_IWRITE);
    if(SD< 0){
        printf("\nshm_open() error \n"); 
        return EXIT_FAILURE; 
    }
    fchmod(SD, S_IRWXU|S_IRWXG|S_IRWXO); 
    if(ftruncate(SD, sizeof(MemData))< 0){
        printf ("ftruncate() error \n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE; 
    }
    //THE FOLLOWING TYPECASTING AVOIDS THE NEED TO ATTACH THROUGH shmat() in shm.h HEADER I GUESS.
    M=(struct MemData*)mmap(NULL, sizeof(MemData), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, SD, 0);
    if(M== MAP_FAILED){
        printf("mmap() error");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }else{
        M->FileName=(char*)"xaa";
        M->LastByteLength=0;
        M->ReadPointer=-1;
        M->WritePointer=-1;
        memset(M->Data, '\0', strlen(M->Data));
    }
    /*
    FILE *FP= fopen(FileName, "rb");
    if(FP!= NULL){
        unsigned long int FilePosition;
        fseek(FP, 0, SEEK_SET);
        FilePosition=ftell(FP);
        fclose(FP);
    }
    */
    close(SD);
    return 0;
}
```

The Reader.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main(void){
    struct MemData{
        char* FileName;
        int LastByteLength;
        int ReadPointer;
        int WritePointer;
        char Data[512000];//MEMORY BLOCK SIZE: 500 KB
    };
    int SD;
    struct MemData *M;
    int NumberOfBuffers=10;
    int BufferSize=51200;//FILE BUFFER SIZE 50 KB

    SD= shm_open("/program.shared", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, S_IREAD|S_IWRITE);
    if(SD< 0){
        printf("\nshm_open() error \n"); 
        return EXIT_FAILURE; 
    }
    fchmod(SD, S_IRWXU|S_IRWXG|S_IRWXO); 
    if(ftruncate(SD, sizeof(MemData))< 0){
        printf ("ftruncate() error \n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE; 
    }
    //THE FOLLOWING TYPECASTING AVOIDS THE NEED TO ATTACH THROUGH shmat() in shm.h HEADER I GUESS.
    M=(struct MemData*)mmap(NULL, sizeof(MemData), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, SD, 0);
    if(M== MAP_FAILED){
        printf("mmap() error");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }else{
        printf("\n%s", M->FileName);
        printf("\n%d", M->LastByteLength);
        printf("\n%d", M->ReadPointer);
        printf("\n%d", M->WritePointer);
    }
    /*
    FILE *FP= fopen(FileName, "rb");
    if(FP!= NULL){
        unsigned long int FilePosition;
        fseek(FP, 0, SEEK_SET);
        FilePosition=ftell(FP);
        fclose(FP);
    }
    */
    munmap(M,sizeof(MemData));
    close(SD);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which process segfaults, the reader or writer? I assume it's the reader; what happens if you comment out the `printf("\n%s", M->FileName);` line?

Comment: let me check.Now no Segmentation Fault after commenting the printf("\n%s", M->FileName);  line

Comment: @John, how can I fix this printf() line?

Comment: Filename points to non-shared memory in the Writer process.  Change it to `char Filename[100];`

Comment: @stark, I have changed according to your suggestion and then this assignment M->FileName="xaa";causes the error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘const char [4]’ to ‘char [128]’

Comment: You have to copy the data to shared memory.  Example `sprintf(Filename, "xaa");`

Comment: `memset(M->Data, '\0', strlen(M->Data));` <<-- huh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments, the issue is because of the way you're assigning and passing the `FileName` value.

`M->FileName=(char*)"xaa";`

This results in `M->FileName` holding a pointer to a string in the writer process' memory. Dereferencing this pointer in the reader process results in a segmentation fault due to the filename being stored in the writer process memory, which is not shared with the reader. You need to store the characters themselves in the shared memory, not a pointer to writer process memory.

If you can safely assume the maximum length of the filename string, you can change your struct to store the entire string rather than a pointer: change `char* FileName;` to `char FileName[256];` or some other fixed length value. You will need to use `strcpy` rather than direct assignment after making this change: change `M->FileName=(char*)"xaa";` to `strcpy(M->FileName, "xaa");`.

If you want a dynamic length string, you can call `mmap` again to allocate shared memory for just the string, and then store the pointer to this shared memory string in `FileName`.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to store FileName in the Struct?

Comment: See my edit. You can change the string to be a fixed width character array or allocate the string in shared memory as well

Comment: I have changed according to your suggestion and then this assignment M->FileName="xaa";causes the error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘const char [4]’ to ‘char [128]’

Comment: Use `strcpy` instead of direct assignment. Edited answer